# Matrix notation for weighted sum of squares

Tags: least-squares, sums-of-squares, weighted-least-squares

While going through page 1 of [Lecture 24: Weighted and Generalized Least Squares](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat401/lecture-24.pdf) [PDF], I got the following questions. 
Weighted sum of squares is defined as below: 
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{n}{w_i(Y_i - X_ib)^2}$$
And this could be written in matrix notation as follows
$$(Y−Xb)'W(Y−Xb)$$

Only thing I did not get is how $W$ (weights) got into the middle? And why should it be a diagonal matrix?

I get that $\sum_{}x^2$ could be written as $X^T * X $. But how $\sum_{}wx^2$ is written as $X^TWX$ , any clue?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for the edits, I get that $\sum_{}x^2$ could be written as $X^T * X $. But how $\sum_{}wx^2$ is written as $X^TWX$ , any clue??

Comment: To weight the rows of a matrix, left-multiply by a diagonal matrix. To weight the columns of a matrix, right-multiply by a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2721222/339790

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
w_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & w_2 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & w_n \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} w_1x_1 \\ w_2x_2 \\ \vdots \\ w_nx_n \end{bmatrix} \\[3mm]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i^2
\end{align}